# why does cv2.resize not work in the loop?

Tags: python, opencv

I am working on a CNN model and I am preparing the data.
This code works perfectly:

```
img = X_pre_train[0]
cv2.resize(img,(224,224))
```

But as soon as i try to do it in a loop, it does not work anymore

```
[cv2.resize(img,(224,224),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA) for img in X_pre_train]
```

The error message is:

```
error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3720: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

I am working on Google Colab. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Because you have something in `X_pre_train` that is not an image...

Comment: this is whats in 'X_pre_train[0]':
array([[255, 255, 255, ...,  25,  22,  21],
       [255, 255, 255, ...,  25,  22,  21],
       [255, 255, 255, ...,  25,  22,  20],
       ...,
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 121, 122, 123],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 120, 121, 122],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 120, 121, 122]], dtype=uint8)

Comment: The error apparently is not caused by `X_pre_train[0]`...

Comment: yes thank you @QuangHoang, i found another image in X_pre_train that was empty!